# What can I look for to check if a project is set up as a "managed Expo project"

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to understand React Native development environment. I'm using Visual Code in Windows.
I've got a simple project A that I set up using the Expo tutorial as a "Managed Expo Project".  Just a simple page and I'm trying to use a checkbox component.

I've got another inherited React Native project B, and I want to find out if it's a "Managed Expo Project" or a "Bare React native" project.  It does include Expo, but I have read that even a Bare React Native Project can include expo.

**So: Is there a setting on a line in a config file somewhere that makes it one or the other? ie Does the existence of   "expo": "~40.0.0", in dependencies in package.json define it?**

(I came to this point because I'm trying to use CheckBox from "@react-native-community/checkbox". Project B  builds fine when using this, but my simple project A does not.  I see on Expo website that this does not work with Expo, and that we are supposed to use a component Expo-Checkbox instead.  SO I wanted to confirm the 2 projects are both expo-managed.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run `npx expo-env-info` in your project and it will tell you what workflow you're using. The heuristics used to determine your project type are:

1. do you have an `ios` directory or `android` directory?
2. do you have `react-native-unimodules` in your `package.json`?

Usually people end up with a bare workflow project by accident when they eject and then don't properly revert their project once they decide to abort.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful!   So, they are both Expo apps. And they do not have react-native-unimodules in the package.json. Does the existence of react-native-unimodules definitely mean that an app is NOT a managed-expo app?   I haven't been able to glean that info from the documentation, because it mentions expo.

Comment: PS turns out that I was having trouble with @react-native-community/checkbox only when trying to run in a web browser (via metro).   When I run on my device, both apps ran fine. But that's a different issue...

Comment: react-native-unimodules does indeed mean it is not a managed app. there is no need to install it in a managed app

Comment: Thanks. really helpful, Just now `diagnostics` is deprecated. So use `npx expo-env-info` instead

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install expo-env-info
npm expo-env-info
```

Outputs

```
...
Expo Workflow: bare
```